$\mathbb CP(2)$ as cellulation/combinatorial manifold
By a "cellulation" I mean something like a piece-wise linear triangulation, just with general $n$-cells instead of $n$-simplices. For example, $\mathbb RP(2)$ has a very simple cellulation with one 2-gon 2-cell whose two boundary edges are identified in the according way.
Question: Is there any simple cellulation of $\mathbb CP(2)$?
During my search I found this triangulation with 9 vertices. However, this assumes that any subsimplex can only be once in the boundary of a larger simplex, which I don't need and which might make the construction more complex than necessary. I also found the CW decomposition given in the ncat lab which consists of a 4-ball whose boundary $S_3$ is collapsed onto a 2-sphere. In contrast, I need a "cellulation", where the boundary of each $n$-cell is identified with a $n-1$-cellulation.
Is there any way to turn the CW complex into a cellulation? Maybe something along these lines: The kernel of the projection $S_3\rightarrow S_2$ is $S_1$, so we replace $S_2$ in the CW complex with a 4-volume whose boundary is $S_2\times S_1$?
Added: I just stumbled over this mathoverflow answer, which might answer my question. For $n=3$, I'm extracting the following cell complex:

1 0-cell
1 1-cell
4 2-cells, namely 3 1-gons and a 4-gon. The 4-gon with opposite edges glued cellulates the $Z_{\{1,2,3\}}\simeq S_1^2$ in the linked answer.
3 3-cells, each equal to the product of a 1-gon and an edge. The boundary consists of 2 1-gons and 1 4-gon. Gluing the two 1-gons yields the cellulation for $Z_{\{1,2\}}$, $Z_{\{1,3\}}$, or $Z_{\{2,3\}}$, which are solid tori $\simeq S_1\times B_2$.
3 4-cells. The boundary consists of 2 of the 3-cells. Each of the 3-cells has its own two boundary 1-gons glued, and then the resulting solid tori are glued at their boundary 4-gons to yield a cellulation of $Z_{\{1\}}$, $Z_{\{2\}}$, or $Z_{\{3\}}$, all $\simeq B_4$.

Can anyone tell me if I'm interpreting the linked answer correctly, and if the above indeed yields a cellulation of $\mathbb CP(2)$?
